# Entity Framework DbContext is trying to insert data, that already exists

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two `DbContext` classes. The `ServerContext` has foreign key to `UserContext`.

**ServerContext:**

```
public ServerContext(DbContextOptions<ServerContext> options)
  : base(options) {
}

public DbSet<Server> Server { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<Server>().ToTable("Server");

    builder.Entity<User.User>().HasMany(x => x.Servers).WithOne(x => x.User);
}
```

**Server:**

```
public class Server 
{
    public string ServerId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User.User User { get; set; }
}
```

**UserContext:**

```
public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<User> 
{
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options)
      : base(options) 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
    }
}
```

**User:**

```
public class User : IdentityUser 
{
    public virtual ICollection<Server.Server> Servers { get; set; }
}
```

On startup I'm fetching all `Server` data into the cache and updating it every minute.

The error happens in the model. On the Model I'm using the server data.
After it, I'm checking if the server data contains a non null user data.
Is it null, I'm loading it from the database (in this step the error is thrown).

```
public async Task OnGetAsync() 
{
    Servers = await this.ServerManager.GetServersAsync();

    foreach (var server in Servers) 
    {
        if(server == null) 
            continue;

        // This code triggers the error
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(server.UserId);

        if(user == null) 
           continue;

        server.User = user;
    }
}
```

**User:**

```
  public class User : IdentityUser {

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Server.Server> Servers { get; set; }
  }
```

6 queries for one user data:
https://pastebin.com/ud9eeKKe

After every minute I'm saving the data and I'm getting the following error:

> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. 
>   See the inner exception for details. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException:
>   Duplicate entry '2f2469d5-b35e-42d8-a90c-a6cc3b899b5a' for key 'PRIMARY'  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry '2f2469d5-b35e-42d8-a90c-a6cc3b899b5a' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: Could you change the code of ServerManager.GetServersAsync()?

Comment: Yes I can do this. It's custom Manager.

Comment: Then you could Include the User with the Servers and remove the error-causing code.

Comment: But I dont want to fetch all data from database. Performance reasons.

Comment: What’s all data? Differs the Identity-User from the other user?

Comment: I'm using a custom Useridentity with multple tables.

Comment: Btw you could use fluent Api or Data-Anotation-Attributes. The both of them seem a bit "overdressed".

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, that you could change the code of the GetServersAsync method, I expect the DbContext-Call looks similar to this:

```
return ServerContext.Servers;
```

You could change it to:

```
return ServerContext.Servers.Include(u=>u.User);
```

This way, you could skip the error causing code outside, because the User is already populated.

The error actually occurs, because you set the User-Property to a tracked Entity.

Alternatively, you can set the User-Property null, before saving. 
Or you could set the User as EntityEntry as unchanged before setting the User as User-Property (for Performance-issues, I wouldn’t recommend this).

As another option you could integrate Lazy-Loading, which was introduced with EF Core 2.1 as described [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading).

Update:

You could load your servers NotTracked to prevent the saving issue:

```
return ServerContext.Servers.AsNoTracking();
```

Then you could add the User, like you already do...
Later, before saving the servers, you have to do the following steps:

1. Set the User null again
2. Add the Server-Object as Updated to the Context
3. Call SaveChanges

Comment: Nearly, im using a cached system behind. The thing is: example i'm fetching every minute 10.000 objects from the database include the user (include userdetails, usersettings, ....) But i never need the 10.000 objects with user data. Unnecessary load.

Comment: @TimoFalter So how you filter, which Servers/Users, you need?

Comment: On my view im loading the first 25 objects include the user. In background im refreshing all server objects.

Comment: @TimoFalter So what would you prefer? Lazy Loading or Context.Entry? I think both could fit your needs.

Comment: @TimoFalter Should the User be updated by Savechanges? Otherwise there is another way.

Comment: Not really. Currently I'm only reading the data. Lazy loading could be the solution. I need to test it.

Comment: Lazy loading fix my problem, but lazy load from the user all data (~ 5 queries ), but I dont want all it. Is there are other way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TimoFalter If you only want to show the user, there is another option. I‘ll update my Answer.

Comment: Added user class.

Comment: You could create a slim user-class, that is mapped only to the Properties you need in the View and use Select on the context.

Comment: Which User-Properties do you need for the View?